# ubuntu 16.04 LTS dual monitor - only top menu bar duplicated

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

[image]

I am using 2 monitors, one by HDMI and the second by VGA. Extension works fine and I can have only one left icon bar. BUT there is a duplicate top menu bar which I cannot avoid duplication. Is it possible to have one extended top menu bar? If yes, can any one have a good idea? If there is a duplicate posting, please let me know. There is my `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192

VGA-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  

HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

---

```
$ sudo lshw -C video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:30 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

AND I have nvidia-381. These two monitors work fine at windows 10.

Comment: It should be possible to have one extended top bar with NVidia, if you are using that, by adjusting the settings in the NVidia settings panel so that they are presented as one screen. However, xrandr cannot be used to manage the display then. There are also possibly other caveats to doing this, for various applications.

Comment: @dessert Thanks for editing the code. It looks much nicer than my original posting.

Comment: @dobey do you know any good example to show howa to adjust through NVidia? It's not a big issue for me so far but I want to try a shot.

Comment: No, but the TwinView options in the nvidia control panel should be fairly obvious. And you can read the driver docs.